Render JavaScript code chunk console output
I would like to write some JavaScript in RMarkdown and print the results into the knitted document. Is there some simple way to render stuff into the document, e.g. with console.log() calls? I found out I can create new div elements and append them to the document's DOM, however, that would require a lot of boilerplate as a general solution.
E.g. say I have the following code chunk:
```{js}
function foo() {
   return "foo"
}

console.log(foo())
```

I would like some output chunk like this get rendered below:
> foo

Any ideas?

It sounds like you are requesting the javascript be evaluated during the knitting process before the results get passed to pandoc for conversion.
Therefore you would need to register a custom knitting engine to evaluate the code and return the results. Here are two examples that uses the {chromote} package:
Option 1
Don't use console.log() and just return the output from the javascript.
---
title: "Custom JS Knitr"
output: html_document
date: "2024-04-25"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

knitr::knit_engines$set(my_js = function(options) {
  code <- paste(options$code, collapse = "\n")
  b <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()
  out <- b$Runtime$evaluate(code)$result$value
  knitr::engine_output(options, options$code, out)
})
```

```{my_js}
function foo() {
  return "foo"
};

foo();
```

Option 2
Use console.log() after registering a callback on messages added to the console and return the message text.
---
title: "Custom JS Knitr"
output: html_document
date: "2024-04-25"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

knitr::knit_engines$set(my_js = function(options) {
  code <- paste(options$code, collapse = "\n")
  b <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()
  console_log <- NULL
  b$Console$messageAdded(callback = \(x) console_log <<- c(console_log, x$message$text[[1]]))
  out <- b$Runtime$evaluate(code)$result$value
  knitr::engine_output(options, options$code, console_log)
})
```

```{my_js}
console.log("Hello world")
```


That's exactly what I'm looking for, but sadly it's not working... My r code chunk looks like {r, eval = TRUE, echo = TRUE} x = c(1,2,3,4,5) print(x)  and I get as expected two boxes of output in my html. But with {my_js} console.log("Hello world") (and of course the {r setup, include=FALSE} ... part) only one box is in the output. The code is there but the console output (Hello world) is missing. Do you have any hints?

I'm not entirely sure why you want to use console.log(), but I've added a second example that will work for either your console.log(foo()) in the question example or your console.log("Hello world") comment example.
